# Warning: fwrite(): in ... with no error detail

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2

I'm actually trying to connect on smtp.gmail.com with zend framework 2 via wamp on windows to send a Mail.

I have the same mail.local.php than my coworker (who work on mac), i configured php and apache to enable php_openssl and mod_ssl. I removed all read-only right on my www repository. I launched a telnet on smtp.gmail.com to test and it work.

And finally, it doesn't work and I have those errors :

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Warning: fwrite(): in C:\wamp\www\***\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol.php on line 245

SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Could not read from smtp.gmail.com' in C:\wamp\www\***\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol.php on line 289
Zend\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not read from smtp.gmail.com in C:\wamp\www\***\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol.php on line 289
```

I googled for hours and found nothing on the internet, but i think it maybe a configuration or windows problem. Anyone could help me ?

EDIT :

```
return [
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'mail_transport' => function(ServiceManager $sm) {

                $smtpOptions = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions();

                $smtpOptions->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
                    ->setConnectionClass('plain')
                    ->setName('gmail')
                    ->setPort(587)
                    ->setConnectionConfig(array(
                        'ssl'       => 'tls',
                        'username'  => '***********************@gmail.com',
                        'password'  => '***********************',
                    ));

                return new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp($smtpOptions);
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: please post the mail.local.php (remove password and username)